# VBS to trigger another vbs via cmd in cscript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, wsh

I have a VBScript that triggers tests in HP ALM to be run with UFT
- This vbs works only by triggering it in `cmd` with `cscript`.

I want to know how I can refrain from first going to `cmd` to trigger it, but just create another vbs that will trigger the file to be run in `cmd` with `cscript`. Or maybe you have a better solution.

The below code does not work.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

oShell.run "cmd.exe"   "" c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\Temp\Unattended.vbs""

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples how to run the VBS. If your system runs cscript by default the last option should work.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'run with wscript
objShell.Run("""C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe"" ""C:\Test\MyScript.vbs""")

wscript.sleep 5000 'waits 5 seconds before running the next script. This is used for display purposes, not because you have to

'run with cscript
objShell.Run("""C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe"" ""C:\Test\My Script.vbs""")

wscript.sleep 5000 'waits 5 seconds before running the next script. This is used for display purposes, not because you have to

'run with the default program for vbs files (usually cscript)
objShell.Run("""C:\Test\My Script.vbs""")
```

Comment: Please remove the parentheses. They're not invalid here, but [don't do what most people would expect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx). Also, the default interpreter is `wscript.exe` unless you change it to `cscript.exe`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers really?, it's not a Sub...why not just do `result = objShell.Run("""C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe"" ""C:\Test\My Script.vbs""")` and be done with it *(just remember to `Dim result` first)*.

Comment: @Lankymart That would be another (arguably better) option. If you actually check the returned exit code, that is.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thing is because it's not a `Sub` it's technically not invalid as the `Run()` method is a `Function`, so brackets are fine and will not cause the script to fail. The rocky ground is when you call a `Sub` like this `mySub(arg1)` and `(arg1)` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @Lankymart No. Functions and subs are alike in this respect. `myFunc(arg1)` and `mySub(arg1)` will both work as standalone statements. Not because it's the correct syntax for passing an argument, but because the parentheses enforce `arg1` to be passed by value. `myFunc(arg1, arg2)` and `mySub(arg1, arg2)` will both fail, because that syntax is only valid when used like this: `ret = myFunc(arg1, arg2)`, `Call mySub(arg1, arg2)`, etc. Otherwise it must be `myFunc arg1, arg2` and `mySub arg1, arg2` (without parentheses) for both subs and functions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Your right, I thought functions were different but I stand corrected. As I tend to use `Call mySub(arg1, arg2)` anyway I don't come across these issues very often *(another reason to use `Call`)*.